# Oracle Show only Columns that have changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an audit table which has columns prefixed with "old_" and "new_" to indicate old and new values as below:

```
 ID              <-- Primary Key
 old_cust_name
 new_cust_name
 old_address
 new_address
```

Does anybody knows of readily available package/procedure which can dynamically generate code to produce report and show column changes, something similar to below:

```
 Example

         ID     old_name   new_name   old_address  new_address
         101      Andru     Andrew      Main_St      Main_St
         102      Bill      Bill        1st_Av       2nd_Av
         103      jack      jack        High_St      High_St

 Output 

         101   name changed    : Andru  --> Andrew
         102   address changed : 1st_Av --> 2nd_Av
         103   no change
```

Comment: What would it look like with multiple changes?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - in that case, output will have multiple lines for same ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case..when` expression as

```
select case 
       when nvl(old_name,new_name||'x') != nvl(new_name,old_name||'x') then 
         ID||'   name changed    : '||old_name||' --> '||new_name
       when nvl(old_address,new_address||'x') != nvl(new_address,old_address||'x') then  
         ID||'   address changed : '||old_address||' --> '||new_address            
       else
         ID||'   no change'
       end as "Output" 
  from t;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e7ce5cf085945de2566970cf23804a1)</kbd>

Comment: NULL / not NULL will always be reported as not  changed. If name changed , address change will not be reported.

Comment: @Barbros - very close to what I am looking for. Just that it should work for any table.

Comment: For everybody's benefit - a similar package is available at https://www.orafaq.com/node/1826

Comment: @oradbanj you may use dynamical query by looping through data dictionary views with `execute immediate` statements to be able use for any type of tables. By the way, you already shared such a link which explains about `execute immediate`

Comment: @Serg nice catch! thank you. I changed by `nvl()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so for the fun of it I created a somewhat convoluted query that will generate a SQL statement to compare old and new values. It figures out the primary key columns and the column list based on Oracle data dictionary and your rule that they start with "NEW_" and "OLD_". Just substitute your schema owner and table_name in the first part of it.

I did not test it thoroughly to the point where I can safely say there may be no bugs or it will not "misbehave". But it seems to be working for this simple test case.

I borrowed from Barbaros Özhan solution as well, so thank you for that.

```
with tab as (
select owner, table_name
  from dba_tables t where t.owner = 'FSITJA' and table_name in ('TEST_COMPARE')),
col_list as (
select co.owner,
       co.table_name,
       cn.column_name new_col_name,
       co.column_name old_col_name,
       row_number() over (partition by co.owner, co.table_name order by co.column_name) position,
       decode(row_number() over (partition by co.owner, co.table_name order by co.column_name),
              count(*) over (partition by co.owner, co.table_name),
              'Y',
              'N') last_col
  from dba_tab_columns cn
  join dba_tab_columns co on co.owner = cn.owner
                             and co.table_name = cn.table_name
                             and regexp_replace(co.column_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') = regexp_replace(cn.column_name, '^NEW_(.*)$', '\1')
 where (co.owner, co.table_name) in (select owner, table_name from tab)
       and regexp_like(cn.column_name, '^NEW_')),
pk_col_list as (
select c.owner,
       c.table_name,
       cc.column_name,
       cc.position,
       decode(cc.position, max(cc.position) over (partition by c.owner, c.table_name), 'Y', 'N') last_col       
  from dba_constraints c
  join dba_cons_columns cc on c.owner = cc.owner
                              and c.table_name = cc.table_name
                              and c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
 where (c.owner, c.table_name) in (select owner, table_name from tab)
       and c.constraint_type = 'P'
) --
select replace(replace(extract(xmlconcat(xmlelement("xml_part", sql_select),
                                         xmlelement("xml_part", xml_pkcol_list),
                                         xmlelement("xml_part", xml_col_list),
                                         xmlelement("xml_part", from_t)), '/xml_part/text()'),
                       chr(38)||'apos;', ''''),
               chr(38)||'gt;', '>') full_sql
  from (select pl.owner,
               pl.table_name,
               'SELECT ' || chr(10) sql_select,
               extract(xmlagg(xmlelement("column_name", '       ' || pl.column_name || ',' || chr(10)) order by pl.position), '/column_name/text()') xml_pkcol_list
          from pk_col_list pl
         group by pl.owner,
                  pl.table_name,
                  'SELECT ' || chr(10)) part1
  join (select cl.owner,
               cl.table_name,
               extract(xmlagg(xmlelement("column_name", '       CASE WHEN nvl(' || cl.old_col_name || ', ' || cl.new_col_name || 
                                                        '||''1'') != nvl(' || cl.new_col_name || ', ' || cl.old_col_name || '||''1'')' || chr(10) ||
                                                        '            THEN ''' || regexp_replace(cl.old_col_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') || 
                                                        ' changed: '' || nvl(to_char(' || cl.old_col_name || '), ''''''NULL'''''') || '' --> '' || nvl(to_char(' || cl.new_col_name || 
                                                        '), ''''''NULL'''''')' || chr(10) ||
                                                        '            ELSE ''' || regexp_replace(cl.old_col_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') || 
                                                        ' unchanged'' END AS ' || regexp_replace(cl.old_col_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') ||
                                                        decode(cl.last_col, 'N', ',') || chr(10)
                             ) order by cl.position), '/column_name/text()') xml_col_list,
               '  FROM ' || cl.owner || '.' || cl.table_name || ' t;' from_t
          from col_list cl
         group by cl.owner,
                  cl.table_name,
                  '  FROM ' || cl.owner || '.' || cl.table_name || ' t;') part2 on part1.owner = part2.owner and part1.table_name = part2.table_name;
```

And a sample execution follows:

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> create table fsitja.test_compare (id number primary key,
  2                                    new_name varchar2(10),
  3                                    old_name varchar2(10),
  4                                    new_salary number,
  5                                    old_salary number,
  6                                    new_address varchar2(30),
  7                                    old_address varchar2(30));

Table created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> insert into fsitja.test_compare values (1, 'John', 'James', 1000, 1000, '123 That Road', '332 This Avenue');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> insert into fsitja.test_compare values (2, 'Pat', 'Pat', 1200, 2000, 'None', 'None');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> insert into fsitja.test_compare values (3, 'Jack', null, 5000, 5000, 'None', 'None');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> insert into fsitja.test_compare values (4, 'Dean', 'Dean', null, 900, 'None', 'DIFF ADDRESS');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> insert into fsitja.test_compare values (5, 'Anne', 'Anne', null, null, null, null);

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> commit;

Commit complete.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56>
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:56> with tab as (
  2  select owner, table_name
  3    from dba_tables t where t.owner = 'FSITJA' and table_name in ('TEST_COMPARE')),
  4  col_list as (
  5  select co.owner,
  6         co.table_name,
  7         cn.column_name new_col_name,
  8         co.column_name old_col_name,
  9         row_number() over (partition by co.owner, co.table_name order by co.column_name) position,
 10         decode(row_number() over (partition by co.owner, co.table_name order by co.column_name),
 11                count(*) over (partition by co.owner, co.table_name),
 12                'Y',
 13                'N') last_col
 14    from dba_tab_columns cn
 15    join dba_tab_columns co on co.owner = cn.owner
 16                               and co.table_name = cn.table_name
 17                               and regexp_replace(co.column_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') = regexp_replace(cn.column_name, '^NEW_(.*)$', '\1')
 18   where (co.owner, co.table_name) in (select owner, table_name from tab)
 19         and regexp_like(cn.column_name, '^NEW_')),
 20  pk_col_list as (
 21  select c.owner,
 22         c.table_name,
 23         cc.column_name,
 24         cc.position,
 25         decode(cc.position, max(cc.position) over (partition by c.owner, c.table_name), 'Y', 'N') last_col
 26    from dba_constraints c
 27    join dba_cons_columns cc on c.owner = cc.owner
 28                                and c.table_name = cc.table_name
 29                                and c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
 30   where (c.owner, c.table_name) in (select owner, table_name from tab)
 31         and c.constraint_type = 'P'
 32  ) --
 33  select replace(replace(extract(xmlconcat(xmlelement("xml_part", sql_select),
 34                                           xmlelement("xml_part", xml_pkcol_list),
 35                                           xmlelement("xml_part", xml_col_list),
 36                                           xmlelement("xml_part", from_t)), '/xml_part/text()'),
 37                         chr(38)||'apos;', ''''),
 38                 chr(38)||'gt;', '>') full_sql
 39    from (select pl.owner,
 40                 pl.table_name,
 41                 'SELECT ' || chr(10) sql_select,
 42                 extract(xmlagg(xmlelement("column_name", '       ' || pl.column_name || ',' || chr(10)) order by pl.position), '/column_name/text()') xml_pkcol_list
 43            from pk_col_list pl
 44           group by pl.owner,
 45                    pl.table_name,
 46                    'SELECT ' || chr(10)) part1
 47    join (select cl.owner,
 48                 cl.table_name,
 49                 extract(xmlagg(xmlelement("column_name", '       CASE WHEN nvl(' || cl.old_col_name || ', ' || cl.new_col_name ||
 50                                                          '||''1'') != nvl(' || cl.new_col_name || ', ' || cl.old_col_name || '||''1'')' || chr(10) ||
 51                                                          '            THEN ''' || regexp_replace(cl.old_col_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') ||
 52                                                          ' changed: '' || nvl(to_char(' || cl.old_col_name || '), ''''''NULL'''''') || '' --> '' || nvl(to_char(' || cl.new_col_name ||
 53                                                          '), ''''''NULL'''''')' || chr(10) ||
 54                                                          '            ELSE ''' || regexp_replace(cl.old_col_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') ||
 55                                                          ' unchanged'' END AS ' || regexp_replace(cl.old_col_name, '^OLD_(.*)$', '\1') ||
 56                                                          decode(cl.last_col, 'N', ',') || chr(10)
 57                               ) order by cl.position), '/column_name/text()') xml_col_list,
 58                 '  FROM ' || cl.owner || '.' || cl.table_name || ' t;' from_t
 59            from col_list cl
 60           group by cl.owner,
 61                    cl.table_name,
 62                    '  FROM ' || cl.owner || '.' || cl.table_name || ' t;') part2 on part1.owner = part2.owner and part1.table_name = part2.table_name;

FULL_SQL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
       ID,
       CASE WHEN nvl(OLD_ADDRESS, NEW_ADDRESS||'1') != nvl(NEW_ADDRESS, OLD_ADDRESS||'1')
            THEN 'ADDRESS changed: ' || nvl(to_char(OLD_ADDRESS), '''NULL''') || ' --> ' || nvl(to_char(NEW_ADDRESS), '''NULL''')
            ELSE 'ADDRESS unchanged' END AS ADDRESS,
       CASE WHEN nvl(OLD_NAME, NEW_NAME||'1') != nvl(NEW_NAME, OLD_NAME||'1')
            THEN 'NAME changed: ' || nvl(to_char(OLD_NAME), '''NULL''') || ' --> ' || nvl(to_char(NEW_NAME), '''NULL''')
            ELSE 'NAME unchanged' END AS NAME,
       CASE WHEN nvl(OLD_SALARY, NEW_SALARY||'1') != nvl(NEW_SALARY, OLD_SALARY||'1')
            THEN 'SALARY changed: ' || nvl(to_char(OLD_SALARY), '''NULL''') || ' --> ' || nvl(to_char(NEW_SALARY), '''NULL''')
            ELSE 'SALARY unchanged' END AS SALARY
  FROM FSITJA.TEST_COMPARE t;


FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:21:59> SELECT
  2         ID,
  3         CASE WHEN nvl(OLD_ADDRESS, NEW_ADDRESS||'1') != nvl(NEW_ADDRESS, OLD_ADDRESS||'1')
  4              THEN 'ADDRESS changed: ' || nvl(to_char(OLD_ADDRESS), '''NULL''') || ' --> ' || nvl(to_char(NEW_ADDRESS), '''NULL''')
  5              ELSE 'ADDRESS unchanged' END AS ADDRESS,
  6         CASE WHEN nvl(OLD_NAME, NEW_NAME||'1') != nvl(NEW_NAME, OLD_NAME||'1')
  7              THEN 'NAME changed: ' || nvl(to_char(OLD_NAME), '''NULL''') || ' --> ' || nvl(to_char(NEW_NAME), '''NULL''')
  8              ELSE 'NAME unchanged' END AS NAME,
  9         CASE WHEN nvl(OLD_SALARY, NEW_SALARY||'1') != nvl(NEW_SALARY, OLD_SALARY||'1')
 10              THEN 'SALARY changed: ' || nvl(to_char(OLD_SALARY), '''NULL''') || ' --> ' || nvl(to_char(NEW_SALARY), '''NULL''')
 11              ELSE 'SALARY unchanged' END AS SALARY
 12    FROM FSITJA.TEST_COMPARE t;

  ID ADDRESS                                            NAME                           SALARY
---- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
   1 ADDRESS changed: 332 This Avenue --> 123 That Road NAME changed: James --> John   SALARY unchanged
   2 ADDRESS unchanged                                  NAME unchanged                 SALARY changed: 2000 --> 1200
   3 ADDRESS unchanged                                  NAME changed: 'NULL' --> Jack  SALARY unchanged
   4 ADDRESS changed: DIFF ADDRESS --> None             NAME unchanged                 SALARY changed: 900 --> 'NULL'
   5 ADDRESS unchanged                                  NAME unchanged                 SALARY unchanged

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-10 13:22:06>
```

Hope it helps. Please do let me know if you find issues in it.

Francisco.